# CORS not be changed in html or php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, node.js, cors

I am using a free hosting site so that I can show my group the website I am currently working on. A problem I keep see occurring is that in the console there's the error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://error.hostinger.eu/?. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://sampleclickinggame.esy.es' is therefore not
>   allowed access.

The URL is: http://sampleclickinggame.esy.es/index.html 
The URL is: http://sampleclickinggame.esy.es/index.php

Both of the files produce the error
I have tried to use the PHP method of it but that doesn't work, I have also added an ajax version but that doesn't do anything. I mainly want to keep the file format as html, but if I need to change it I will.

**UPDATE**

The code:

```
 <?php
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>IO Chat</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.7.3/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    $.ajax({
    url: "sampleclickinggame.esy.es",
    type: method,
    // This is the important part
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    // This is the important part
    data: data,
    success: function (response) {
        // handle the response
    },
    error: function (xhr, status) {
        // handle errors
    }
});
    </script>
    <style>
    body{
            margin-top: 30px;
        }
        #messageArea{
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="userFormArea" class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <form id="userForm">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Enter UserName</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="username" />
                        <br />
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="messageArea" class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="well">
                    <h3>Online Users</h3>
                    <ul class="list-group" id="users"></ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="chat" id="chat"></div>

                <form id="messageForm">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Enter Message</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="message"></textarea>
                        <br />
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send Message" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        $(function(){
            var socket = io.connect();
            var $messageForm = $('#messageForm');
            var $message = $('#message');
            var $chat = $('#chat');
            var $messageArea = $('#messageArea');
            var $userFormArea = $('#userFormArea');
            var $userForm = $('#userForm');
            var $users = $('#users');
            var $username = $('#username');

            $messageForm.submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                socket.emit('send message', $message.val());
                $message.val('');
            });

            socket.on('new message', function(data){
                $chat.append('<div class="well"><strong>'+data.user+'</strong>: '+data.msg+'</div>');
            });

            $userForm.submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                socket.emit('new user', $username.val(), function(data){
                    if(data){
                        $userFormArea.hide();
                        $messageArea.show();
                    }
                });
                $username.val('');
            });

            socket.on('get users', function(data){
                var html = '';
                for(var i = 0;i < data.length;i++){
                    html += '<li class="list-group-item">'+data[i]+'</li>';
                }
                $users.html(html);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

For some reason it keeps redirecting to an error page for my hosting site and that's where the error is coming from. And as for the `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` error from the looks of it, it's from the error page aswell

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are trying to make a Cross Origin Request and the server you are calling is not configured to respond to CORS request from the domain you are sending.

Your html is located at http://sampleclickinggame.esy.es
but you are trying to make a server call to http://error.hostinger.eu/?

See how the domains are different? For security reasons the Browser does not allow this. When it sees a CORS request, it sends an OPTIONS request to the server first to see if the server will accept the request from the different domain. If it will, then the request will proceed as normal. In your case it looks like the server is not configured to receive a request from http://sampleclickinggame.esy.es

Your solution is to enable CORS on the server you are making the request to, or you must host everything on the same server/domain.

One last thought:
can I see the javascript that is being used to make this network call? I have seen the browser throw this CORS error a lot when it is actually a problem with the javascript request. The one thing that makes me think you might have javascript error is that the Console on your web page is saying this: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"

Comment: The problem is, I never tried to access that server... and the error there, I am not sure why that is as when I run this code on a localhost it works fine that error is not there.

Comment: can you post the code that gets run after the user presses the login button?